# What does sizeof(int[1]) mean?

Tags: c, macros, linux-kernel, sizeof

I am new to the Linux kernel. I am reading the file `ioctl.h`, there I encountered a macro
`_IOC_TYPECHECK(t)`, which looks like this:

```
#define _IOC_TYPECHECK(t) \
        ((sizeof(t) == sizeof(t[1]) && \
          sizeof(t) < (1 << _IOC_SIZEBITS)) ? \
          sizeof(t) : __invalid_size_argument_for_IOC)
```

Can you explain me this code? In this code, what does `sizeof(t[1])` mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is used to check the validity of the third parameter to the `_IOR`/`_IOW`/`_IOWR` macros, which is supposed to be a type. It checks that the parameter is actually a type (and not a variable or a number), and causes a compiler or linker error otherwise.

- If `t` is a type, then `t[1]` is the type "an array of 1 `t`". This type has the same size as `t`, and therefore `sizeof(t) == sizeof(t[1])` is true.
- If `t` is a number, `sizeof(t)` will fail to compile.
- If `t` is a simple (non-array) variable, then `t[1]` will cause a compiler error.
- If `t` is an array variable, `sizeof(t) == sizeof(t[1])` will be false, and a linker error will be caused (because `__invalid_size_argument_for_IOC` is not defined).

The expression `sizeof(t) < (1 << _IOC_SIZEBITS)` checks that the size of the type `t` does not exceed the maximum allowed for `ioctl`, and causes the same linker error otherwise.

There are still some invalid cases which will not be caught by this macro - for example, when `t` is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: "If `t` is an array variable, `sizeof(t) == sizeof(t[1])` will be false" is that really always true?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: Not for an array of one element, but then you might get a compiler warning for indexing the array out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

It means the same as all other uses of `sizeof`. It computes the size of the expression.

In this particular case, I suspect that the check is intended to ensure some property of `t` (which should be a type name, not a variable) which I don't know from the context ... Perhaps that it's possible to treat it as a pointer (needed for the array indexing) which would rule out some types. The comment next to the macro says `/* provoke compile error for invalid uses of size argument */` which seems to support this theory.

Note that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. The parenthesis are not needed, except when you want to compute the size of a type directly, and then they're part of the expression (it's a cast expression). So this could be written `sizeof t == sizeof t[1] && ...`, or maybe `(sizeof t == sizeof t[1])` for clarity.

This is a very good style to use, since it "locks" the size being computed to the proper array, instead of repeating the type of `t`. So, if the type were to change, the expression would automatically adapt and still compute the right thing.

Many C programmers seem to prefer having parenthesis around the argument to `sizeof` in all cases, for some reason.

Comment: `t` here is supposed to be a type, not a variable. It's the third parameter to the [_IOR](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/dev_doc/DOCUMENTATION/HTML/DDK_R2/DOCS/HTML/MAN/MAN9/0028___R.HTM)/_IOW/_IOWR macros.

Comment: I Did Not Know that `sizeof`'s params were optional except for a type; or that they're technically a cast in that case. +1 just for that!

Comment: "and then they're part of the expression". I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. A type identifier (like `int`) doesn't need to have parentheses and isn't an expression but the parentheses are required in `sizeof(int)` because that's the grammar rules... or were you getting at something different? Also, this isn't a cast either.

Comment: @CharlesBailey A type name such as `int` needs to be converted into a cast expression (`(int)`) if you want to pass it to `sizeof`. You can't say `sizeof int`, but `sizeof (int)` is fine. The parenthesis "belong" to the argument, i.e. the argument is `(int)`, they don't belong to `sizeof` as is the case for a function call.

Comment: @unwind There are two grammar rules for unary expressions in C involving `sizeof`: "`sizeof` _unary-expression_" and "`sizeof` `(` _type-name_ `)`". `(int)` isn't a cast expression (it isn't an expression at all), it's just a _type-name_ in parentheses such as you might put after the `sizeof` token.

Comment: Since `t` is a type, the second half of your answer about omitting the parentheses is incorrect (the parentheses must be used here). And the first half is basically "I don't know".